# Сохранение файла в БД (оптимизация)

Tags: php, firebase, инспекция-кода

Если это имеет значение, БД: `firebird`.
Вспомагательная функция:

```
define('MAX_SEGMENT_SIZE', 65535);
function blob_create($data) {
    if (strlen($data) == 0)
        return false;
    $handle = ibase_blob_create();
    $len = strlen($data);
    for ($pos = 0; $pos < $len; $pos += MAX_SEGMENT_SIZE) {
        $buflen = ($pos + MAX_SEGMENT_SIZE > $len) ? ($len - $pos) : MAX_SEGMENT_SIZE;
        $buf = substr($data, $pos, $buflen);
        ibase_blob_add($handle, $buf);
    }
    return ibase_blob_close($handle);
}
```

В данный момент сохранение работает так:

```
else if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] == 'callback'){
    $database   = "***********";
    $user       = "SYSDBA";
    $ps   = "1";

    $dbh = ibase_connect($database, $user, $ps, 'utf8') or die(json_encode(array('message' => 'not connection', 'successed' => false)));

    for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($_FILES['img']['name']); $i++){
        $stmt = "insert into file (name, content, file_type,resource_name, identifier) values ('" . $_FILES['img']['name'][$i] . "','" . blob_create(file_get_contents($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i])) . "', '" . $_FILES['img']['type'][$i] . "','callback','1')";

        $query = ibase_prepare($stmt); 
        $rs = ibase_execute($query) or die(json_encode(array('message' => 'request error', 'successed' => false)));
        ibase_free_query($query);
        ibase_free_result($rs);
    }

    echo "success";exit;
}
```

На локалке все хорошо. Но вот на хостинге есть границы по запросу, и я в них не влаживаюсь. Подскажите как можно оптимизировать, так как в `php` so so :).

Comment: Обычно файлы хранят в архивах для экономии места на жестком диске, а для скачивания больших файлов используют настройки upload_max_filesize - Максимальный размер загружаемого файла
 max_file_uploads - Максимальное количество одновременных загрузок post_max_size - Максимальный размер отправляемого через POST-запрос файла (Должен быть больше upload_max_filesize).  max_execution_time - Время в течении которого скрипт должен полностью завершить своё исполнение. Для отмены ограничений можно присвоить 0. max_input_time - Время получения всех данные из POST и GET запросов. + не > 500 файлов в папке

Comment: пример для настройки максимального размера файла <?php ini_set("upload_max_filesize ","256M");

Comment: @Mcile я все это понимаю, но не могу этого сделать, т к есть ограничения хостинга. Скрипт должен выполниться за 30 с. Он не выполняется. Есть ошибка по таймауту. Из решений вижу только оптимизацию данного кода. ps знаю что в БД лучше не хранить файлы, и сам бы так и делал с удовольствием. Но есть ТЗ. ДАйнный пункт оспорить не могу.

Comment: а ну это просто - если нужен ответ от сервера на клиенте моментальный - тогда комбинация этих функций позволит закончить соединение клиент сервер, скрипт будет выполняться лишь на сервере session_write_close();
        fastcgi_finish_request();

Comment: и попробуйте увеличить время скрипта ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '2048M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '2048M');
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

Comment: Если уж сервак нельзя трогать - то поможет раздельная отправка файлов с клиента - т.е. клиент отправляет не пачку файлов, а пачку одновременных запросов в каждом запросе по файлу

Comment: Переход на SSD тоже даст ощутимый прирост чтения и записи

Comment: @Mcile спасибо, буду пробовать